# bytes("s","utf-8") > bytes(10000) == True

Tags: python, python-3.x

When compare `bytes("string")` with `bytes(number)`

```
In [212]: bytes("s","utf-8") > bytes(10000)
Out[212]: True
```

I try best to understand it:

```
In [219]: bytes("s", "utf-8"), len(bytes("s", "utf-8"))
Out[219]: (b's', 1)

In [220]: len(bytes(10**))
Out[220]: 100004
```

The number 10^4 which occupy 1000 bytes are less than "s" takes one byte.

How could I understand it intuitively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bytes are ordered lexicographically, like strings, lists, or tuples. So first the leading elements are compared, then the next two, and so forth until one or both of the byte strings end.  So

```
bytes("s", "utf-8") > bytes("r", "utf-8")
# True

bytes("s", "utf-8") > bytes("t", "utf-8")
# False
```

Since `bytes(10000)` makes a `bytes` full of `0`s, any `bytes` containing non-zero bytes will be larger than it, just like a word of all `a`s will come earlier in the dictionary than a word containing any other character.